# Add column for Fiscal Week Number in an SQL SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

Tried to add a custom Fiscal Week column to my DimDate table in a query.

Some background: the fiscal year always begins on 02-01 [February 1]. My DimDate tables earliest date goes to January 01, 2008 [01-01-2008]. I looked at previous posts and tried in the code below, except I got 0 for the Week Number  for 02-01-2008 and 02-02-2008.

```
Datediff(wk, CONVERT(DATE, '2008-02-01'), CONVERT(DATE, dbo.DIMDATE.DATE_VALUE)) AS 'FiscalWeek',
```

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you can just offset the date by 1 month:

```
datepart(wk, dateadd(month, -1, datevalue)) as fiscal_week
```

Depending on your actual requirement, you might want to try `isowk` as well.